# JavaScript Not converting strings to integers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of multiple divs according to their class, and then add them up. The issue I'm having is they aren't converting to strings no matter what I've tried, and instead of multiple rows adding up to "800" it outputs "500200100".

Here is the code for the `.each` function

```
var sum = '';
    $('.tm-xxx').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(($(this).text()));
});
```

What could be a possible solution? I've also tried wrapping the whole `sum += parseInt(($(this).text()))` with parseInt with no success.

Comment: you should initilaize sum to 0

Comment: in js -> string + number = string.

Comment: Why did you initialize `sum` to a string?

Comment: I didn't even notice, I had copied the `.each` function from an earlier function using strings and didn't even think of looking at the sum variable, like an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the sum variable an integer:

```
var sum = 0;
```

It's concatenating strings in your example, not adding integers.

Comment: I didn't even notice, I had copied the `.each` function from an earlier function using strings and didn't even think of looking at the sum variable, like an idiot

Comment: Don't worry - it happens to the best of us. Is it working now?

Comment: yepp, like a charm